# Python 2.7 & Regular Expressions: False if statement returns

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

To practice regular expressions, I'm trying to create a very simple text based game similar to Zork. However I can't seem to have the code work using regular expressions.

**Movement.py**

```
import re

def userMove():
    userInput = raw_input('Which direction do you want to move?')
    textArray = userInput.split()
    analyse = [v for v in textArray if re.search('north|east|south|west|^[NESW]', v, re.IGNORECASE)]

   print textArray
   print analyse

   movement = 'null'
   for string in analyse:
       if string is 'North' or 'n':
          movement = 'North'
       elif string is 'East'or'e':
          movement = 'East'
       elif string is 'South'or's':
          movement = 'South'
       elif string is 'West'or'w':
          movement = 'West'

print movement
```

**if/elif Sample Run**

```
>>> import movement
>>> moves = movement.userMove()
Which direction do you want to move?Lets walk East
['Lets', 'walk', 'East']
['East']
North
```

**if Sample Run**

```
>>> import movement
>>> moves = movement.userMove()
Which direction do you want to move?I`ll run North
['I`ll', 'run', 'North']
['North']
West
```

If the `for` loop will constantly set `movement` to North; and using `if` statements instead of `elif` will set it to West. 
Making the regex use `userInput` in place of `textArray` cause the method to keep `movement` as null.

***Edit***
After further testing and changing the code, I'm sure the regex is fine and it's a bug with the `if` statements or the `for` loop.

Comment: The result of the regular expression, i.e. `analyse`, is never used anywhere in the program?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded a copy I was editing to try and solve the problem, not the actual file with the error. Now (with fixed typos) the code returns null if the input has no accepted strings, but always North if it's one that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with these `if` statements:

```
if string is 'North' or 'n':
    movement = 'North'
elif string is 'East'or'e':
    movement = 'East'
elif string is 'South'or's':
    movement = 'South'
etc...
```

They don't work quite how you're expecting. First, you shouldn't compare strings with `is` - you should use `==`. Secondly, the statement is evaluated more like:

```
if (string is 'North') or 'n':
    movement = 'North'
```

So, `'n'` is always `True` - meaning your `movement` variable is always set to `North`.

Try this instead:

```
if string in ('North', 'n'):
    etc...
```

Comment: No problem! I was surprised nobody had pointed it out before me.

Answer (score 2):

Typo in:

```
 elif string == 'South':
    movement == 'South'
    print 'Go South'
```

Replace == with =

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code. Typo in `if string == 'South':` block & you should use `analyse` instead of `textarray`

```
import re

def userMove():
    userInput = raw_input('Which direction do you want to move?')
    textArray = userInput.split()
    analyse = [v for v in textArray if re.search('[N|n]orth|[E|e]ast|[S|s]outh|[W|w]est', v)]

print analyse

movement = 'null'
for string in analyse:
    if string == 'North':
        movement = 'North'
        print 'Go North'

    elif string == 'East':
        movement = 'East'
        print 'Go East'

    elif string == 'South':
        movement = 'South'
        print 'Go South'

    elif string == 'West':
        movement = 'West'
        print'Go West'

return movement
```